# Not allowing duplicates in IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Guid,string>>

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am using linq to get data and insert the data into a IEnumerable>. But sometimes i get duplicate keyvaluepairs and i dont want that because i am doing a ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value) on the IEnumerable.

this is my code:

```
public Dictionary<Guid, string> GetCitizensWithUnwarrentedAbsence(Guid counselorId, DateTime date)
{
    var now = DateTime.Now;
    var startInterval = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Date.ToShortDateString());
    var endInterval = Convert.ToDateTime(date.Date.ToShortDateString()).AddHours(23).AddMinutes(59);
    var list = (from c in _context.CitizenCounselorSet
                join p in _context.ActivityLessonParticipantSet on c.Citizen.Id equals p.UserId
                where c.CounselorId == counselorId
                      && c.StartDate < now
                      && (c.EndDate == null || (c.EndDate.HasValue && c.EndDate.Value > now))
                      && p.WasUnwarrantedAbsent
                      && !p.ActivityLesson.IsDeleted
                      && !p.ActivityLesson.IsCancelled
                      && p.ActivityLesson.From >= startInterval
                      && p.ActivityLesson.From <= endInterval
                select new
                {
                    UserId = p.UserId,
                    UserName = p.User.FullName,
                    CPR = p.User.UserName
                }).ToList().Select(a => new KeyValuePair<Guid, string>(a.UserId, a.UserName + " (" + EncryptionUtility.DecryptString(a.CPR).Insert(6, "-") + ")"));
    return list.ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);
}
```

How would i make sure not to get duplicates or remove the duplicates after i get the data ??

Comment: Why do you bother creating a list when you convert it into a dictionary anyway? Why don’t you just do the `ToDictionary`?

Comment: If you get duplicates, then that means that the data doesn’t yield unique users. When you actually care about users, why do you select from those other tables then?

Comment: @TimSchmelter doesnt matter just the first one. I am getting the user and the name because i am displaying absent students that didnt show up for a course. If the student didnt show up for 2 courses on the same day for the same teacher then the dictionary will try to insert a duplicate.

Comment: @poke i am selecting from the other tables because i want to know if the user has been absent. And if the user has been absent in two courses with the same teacher in one day then that would result in two entries.. but i only care about displaying the student once

Comment: Call Distinct() on list before calling ToDictionary()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would make couple of changes at the end of the query. Let's save space and start in your `}).ToList()` when your main query logic gets executed and redefine the rest to get your dictionary:

```
var yourExistingQueryLogic = ...
                             }).ToList();

var yourUserDictionary = yourExistingQueryLogic
                         .Select(x=>new {x.UserId, UserName = x.UserName+ " (" + EncryptionUtility.DecryptString(a.CPR).Insert(6, "-") + ")"}) //you can simply build an anonymous object here
                         .Distinct() //this will eliminate duplicates
                         .ToDictionary(x=>x.UserId, x=>x.UserName); // DONE!
```